# how to config apache reverse proxy for multiple jboss remote instances?

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass

I need to setup an apache reverse proxy with multiple jboss instances as target server (with different IP).

I've already set in my DNS an url `http://jboss-test.domain.com` and i would like to redirect my clients to their own jboss server like : `http://jboss1.domain.com/server1/` , `http://jobss2.domain.com/server2/`, and keeping my proxy test url . Some users must have access only at jboss 1 and some other only at jboss2.

The location "server1" and "server2" don't exist in the real jboss url login path `http://jboss1.domain.com/jbossapp/faces/login/pages/login-index.xhtml?environment=WEB`

I'm able to do that only for 1 server at the moment , with the following vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /server1/jbossapp/ http://jboss1.domain.com/jbossapp/
    ProxyPassReverse /server1/jbossapp/ http://jboss1.domain.com/jbossapp/
    ProxyPass / http://jboss1.domain.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://jboss1.domain.com/
    
    Loglevel debug
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/stweb-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/stweb-access_log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

With this conf i can be correctly redirect to the jboss login page, when i call my test proxy URL:

```
http://jboss-test.domain.com/server1/ -> http://jboss-test.domain.com/jbossapp/faces/login/pages/login-index.xhtml?environment=WEB
```

I would like to get someting like :

```
ProxyPass /server1/jbossapp/ http://jboss1.domain.com/jbossapp/
ProxyPassReverse /server1/stweb-dr/ http://jboss1.domain.com/jbossapp/
ProxyPass /server2/jbossapp/ http://jboss2.domain.com/jbossapp/
ProxyPassReverse /server2/stweb-dr/ http://jboss2.domain.com/jbossapp/
ProxyPass / http://jboss1.domain.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://jboss1.domain.com/
ProxyPass / http://jboss2.domain.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://jboss2.domain.com/
```

This last conf doesn't work, as when i call the server2, i'm gonna be redirect anytime to the "/" of the server1

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: What you appear to want is load balancing which is available in Apache with [mod_proxy_balancer](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html)

Comment: Thx but i think load balancing doesn't fix my issue as some users must have access only at jboss1 and some other only at jboss2 , and i need to redirect "/" for both of them , there are some external app deployed on the jboss "/" root instead of under /jbossapp"